# How to swap multiple columns at once directly?

Tags: list-manipulation

## Question

Is there elegant code like `m[[{2, 3;;4}]] = m[[{3;;4, 2}]]`?

---

## Example

1. Swapping column 2 with columns 3 to 4:

#### In:

```
o = 2; t = -2;
lis = Array[x, {2, 5}];
% // MatrixForm
Transpose@Insert[Transpose@Drop[lis, None, {o}], lis[[All, o]], t];
% // MatrixForm
```

#### Out:

[image]

---

2. Swapping columns 2~3 with columns 4~5:

#### In:

```
lis = Array[x, {2, 6}];
% // MatrixForm
Transpose@Insert[Transpose@Drop[lis, None, {2, 3}], lis[[All, 2 ;; 3]], 4];
% // MatrixForm
```

#### Out:

[image]

P.S. As for question *"How to avoid/remove the redundant `{}`?"*
— Answers are in another post: [How to avoid the redundant curly brackets {} when using list parameters/arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164730)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swapping column 2 with columns 3 to 4**

```
lis[[All, {1, 3, 4, 2, 5}]]
```

or

```
lis[[All, Permute[Range[5], Cycles[{{2, 4, 3}}]]]]
```

*Edit: Original Answer*

```
lis.SparseArray[Thread[Rule[Transpose[{{1, 3, 4, 2, 5}, Range[5]}], 1]], {5, 5}]
//MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  x(1,1) & x(1,3) & x(1,4) & x(1,2) & x(1,5) \\
>  x(2,1) & x(2,3) & x(2,4) & x(2,2) & x(2,5) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

or, using `Permute/Cycles` (2-> 4 ->3):

```
lis.SparseArray[Thread[Rule[Transpose[{Permute[Range[5], Cycles[{{2, 4, 3}}]], Range[5]}], 
1]], {5, 5}]
```

**Swapping columns 2~3 with columns 4~5**

```
lis2[[All, {1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6}]]
```

or

```
lis2[[All, Permute[Range[6], Cycles[{{2, 4}, {3, 5}}]]]]
```

*Edit. Original Answer:*

```
 lis2.SparseArray[Thread[Rule[Transpose[{{1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6}, Range[6]}],1]], {6, 6}]
 // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  x(1,1) & x(1,4) & x(1,5) & x(1,2) & x(1,3) & x(1,6) \\
>  x(2,1) & x(2,4) & x(2,5) & x(2,2) & x(2,3) & x(2,6) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

or using `Permute/Cycles` (2->4, 3->5):

```
lis2.SparseArray[Thread[Rule[Transpose[{Permute[Range[6], Cycles[{{2, 4}, {3, 5}}]], 
  Range[6]}], 1]], {6, 6}]
```

where:

```
lis = Array[x, {2, 5}];
lis2 = Array[x, {2, 6}];
```

**Note**
I tried deleting this answer as the first attempt was very poor. I couldn't as the answer had been accepted.  I am sure the simplified solution is not original, so I have opted for community wiki instead. Feel free to modify (or delete).

Comment: I like your approach which has much mathematical taste :)

Comment: @ooo Thanks! It is not often I get a compliment like that.  (Perhaps `Permute/Cycles` is 'the way to go'?)

Answer (score 7):

edit with a more general function:

```
swapRanges[array_, {first_, last_}]:= Module[{temp = array}
, Block[{Span}
  , Span = Apply[Sequence]@*Range
  ; temp[[All, {first, last}]] = temp[[All, {last, first}]]
  ; temp
  ]
]


lis = Array[x, {2, 5}];
```

```
swapRanges[lis, {2;;3, 4;;5}]
```

[image]

```
swapRanges[lis, {;; 2, 3 ;; 5 ;; 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

By in-place modification:

```
lis = Array[x, {2, 5}];

from = 2;
to = 4;
rot = 1;
lis[[All, from ;; to]] = lis[[All, RotateLeft[Range[from, to], rot]]];
lis // MatrixForm
```

By creating a new list

```
lis = Array[x, {2, 5}];
perm = PermutationList[
 Cycles[{RotateLeft[Range[from, to], rot]}], 
 Dimensions[lis][[2]]]
];
result = lis[[All,perm];
result // MatrixForm
```

Comment: I'm 100% sure OP meant those ranges to be adjacent in general. E.g. swap `2` and `4;;5`.

Comment: @Kuba You mean them _not_ to be adjacent? Now I see.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Are there any tips on how to not lose focus during typing one sentence? :(

Comment: @Kuba Haha, none that I know of and that really help...

Answer (score 2):

```
list = Array[x, {2, 5}];
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[RotateLeft, #, {2, 3, 4}] & /@ list
```

[image]