# How to avoid the redundant curly brackets {} when passing list parameters/arguments?

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

(This question comes from [How to swap multiple columns at once directly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164722))

In:

```
(list = Array[x, {2, 6}]) // MatrixForm
Insert[
    Drop[list, None, {2, 3}] // Transpose,
    (*→*) list[[All, 2 ;; 3]] (*←*),
    4
] // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

Out:

[image]

#### Question

How to <del>deal with</del> `Insert` the part — `(*→*)...(*←*)` "elegantly"?

#### Requirements

1. Using `Insert`.
2. Don't let the `{}` get involved in **when** passing parameters instead of removing them **later**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Unevaluated[]`:

```
list = Array[C, {2, 6}];

t = list[[All, 2 ;; 3]];
r = Drop[list, None, {2, 3}];

Insert[r // Transpose, Unevaluated[Sequence @@ Transpose[t]], 4] // Transpose
   {{C[1, 1], C[1, 4], C[1, 5], C[1, 2], C[1, 3], C[1, 6]},
    {C[2, 1], C[2, 4], C[2, 5], C[2, 2], C[2, 3], C[2, 6]}}
```

Answer (score 4):

E.g. add `FlattenAt`

```
FlattenAt[Transpose@Insert[Transpose@Drop[lis, None, {2, 3}], lis[[All, 2 ;; 3]], 4], {{1, 4}, {2, 4}}]
% // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  x(1,1) & x(1,4) & x(1,5) & x(1,2) & x(1,3) & x(1,6) \\
>  x(2,1) & x(2,4) & x(2,5) & x(2,2) & x(2,3) & x(2,6) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternatively:

```
index = Insert[Drop[Range[6], {2, 3}], {2, 3}, 4] //
          Replace[#, List -> Sequence, {2}, Heads -> True] &;
MatrixForm[lis[[All, index]]]
```

Comment: For `FlattenAt` method — How to expediently handle a case that contains many columns?